# Почему counter не инкрементируется?

Tags: javascript

Почему в данной конструкции counter не инкрементируется?

```
var button = document.getElementById("button")

var productCounter = 0

function incrementCounter(counter) {
counter++
console.log(counter)
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  incrementCounter(productCounter);
})
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Nikita_Migushev/qdn7u1ho/7/)

Comment: `counter` то как раз инкрементируется, вы ведь 1 в консоли видите, а не 0. А вот `productCounter` нет, поскольку параметр передается по значению, а не по ссылке. Простые типы в js передаются только по значению.

Answer (score 1):

В javascript по ссылке передаются только объекты и массивы а остальные нет
можно реализовать так

```
var button = document.getElementById("button")

var productCounter = {a: 0}

function incrementCounter(counter) {
counter.a++
console.log(counter.a)
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  incrementCounter(productCounter);
})
```

P.S сейчас вы отправляете значение по функции 0 а в функции делается копия переменной в которому прибавляет 1, оригинал не трогается. js не похож на другие языки где можно просто поставить & и все

Comment: а как сделать, если у меня несколько глобальных каунтеров, пусть, в объекте, и нужно передать в аргументе функции, какой именно каунтер обновить?
Например:
```
var productCounter = {
a: 0,
b: 0
}
```

Comment: Ну примерно вот так` в первом каунтере задействуешь productCounter.a а в втором productCounter.b

Comment: Если все правильно отметь галочку возле ответа