# Функция карусели JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть три слайдшоу - каждый со своей продуктовой линейкой.

Нужно сделать две универсальные функции для карусели: moveLeft и moveRight.

Для карусели используется три каунтера, каждый для своей продуктовой линии.

Как прописать единую функцию, которая принимала бы у себя в аргументе, какой каунтер нужно обновить?

Вот что получается на данный момент, но это не годится:

```
    var productLine1Counter = 0
    var productLine2Counter = 0
    var productLine3Counter = 0

function slidesMoveRigth(counter, slider) {
        counter++
        slider.style.transition = 'margin-left 0.4s ease-in-out';
        slider.style.marginLeft = '-' + 33.1 * counter + '%';
        console.log(counter);
    }

    productLine1NextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        slidesMoveRigth(productLine1Counter, productLine1CarouselSlider)
    })
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что каунтер в данном случае не обновляется.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1050150/223826 вам же объяснили уже, почему не обновляется.

Comment: и лучше в `data` атрибуты текущее значение впишите

Comment: @teran Я понимаю, что с моей стороны это выглядит, как флуд, но я не могу понять, как правильно передать аргументы в такой функции с соответствующими каунтерами? В предыдущем тикете этого ответа нет и там вопрос был сформулирован немного по-другому

Comment: @teran, я понимаю, что не обновляется сейчас каунтер из-за того, что каждый раз передается нулевое значение из глобальной переменной. Но как сделать так, чтобы обновлялся и при том, что не прописывать внутри функции конкретную переменную, которую нужно обновить, а передать ее в аргументе и через аргумент уже обновить?

Comment: вам же ответили, чтобы менять надо сделать объект. объект счетчика можно оставить глобальным, а имя поля которое увеличивать передавать строкой как параметр. Но лучше избавится от этих переменных вовсе и хранить текущие значения в дата-атрибутах, как я написал ранее.

Comment: будет у вас `counters = {p1: 0, p2:0}` передавать будут `moveLeft('p1', ... )` а менять `counters[key]++` И опять же, имя поля - в data-атрибуты

Comment: @teran спасибо, теперь все отлично! Маленький вопросик: почему в moveLeft('p1') - 'p1' в ковычках нужно указывать?